# Maximum satisifed students in best arrangement

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

N students are in line. And we can consider there arrangement best when maximum number of students are satisfied. A student is satisfied if he is the right neighbor of his best friend. Each student has only one best friend. We need to find the number of satisfied students in the best arrangement and the number of different best arrangements. I guess this can be solved by dynamic programming, please help.

Example : Let N=3 and the array is [2,3,1] which mean 1 has 2 as best friend,2 has 3 as best friend and 3 has 1 as best friend.

Maximum two students can be satisfied. There are three possible arrangements of students with maximum number of satisfied students:

```
1) 1 3 2 
2) 3 2 1 
3) 2 1 3
```

Now N can be upto 1000000, so what can be something N or N*LogN approach to tackle this problem

Comment: Ask specific questions about where you're stuck, and show your progress if you expect help

Comment: @SoufianeHassou he is not stuck, he is just a cheater, hoping to get some score in a programming contest :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create a graph in the following manner:
Each student is a node, each "best friend" is an edge between that student and his best friend.

Now you have a [Maximum Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)) problem, and that has already been solved...

Answer (score 0):

Its a question of live contest

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/countercode/challenges/best-photo

you cannot ask such question of live contest .